# Probability of a business succeeding

Tags: probability

I'm looking through an old problem set, and I've been stumped. Here's the question:

Suppose that 1/3 of new businesses fail in one year. Of those remaining after 1 year, 2/3 fail in their second year. Out of a group of 4 businesses, what is the probability that at least one will survive two years?

I've been trying to work with the equivalent probability of $1-Pr$(zero survive after 2 years) but am not making progress. I've additionally tried to enumerate all of the potential conditional probabilities, but that doesn't seem like the right approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probability that a business will fail within 2 years is the probability that it will fail in the first year plus the probability that it will fail in the second year:

$$\begin{align*}P(\text{fail in 2 years}) & = P(\text{fail in year 1})+P(\text{survive year 1})\cdot P(\text{fail in year 2}) \\ & = \dfrac{1}{3}+\left(1-\dfrac{1}{3}\right)\cdot \dfrac{2}{3} \\ & = \dfrac{1}{3}+\dfrac{4}{9} = \dfrac{7}{9}\end{align*}$$

So, the probability that all four businesses will fail within two years is:

$$\left(\dfrac{7}{9}\right)^4$$

And the complement of that is

$$\dfrac{4160}{6561}$$

Answer (score 3):

After one year, $2/3$ of the original businesses are left.  Then $2/3$ of them, or $4/9$ of the original businesses fail in the second year, giving a total failure rate of $$\frac13+\frac49=\frac79,$$ so the probability that a new business survives two years is $\frac29.$  You can test this by assuming there are $9$ business to start.  Three fail in the first year, and $4$ in the second year.

Take it from here.